# Why do updatable package numbers differ between updates-available and apt update list?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

I connected to my Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS server and saw the following message:

```
346 packages can be updated.
229 updates are security updates.
```

Then I ran

```
sudo apt update
```

and it reported

```
336 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

Then I looked back into the updates notifier file:

```
sudo cat /var/lib/update-notifier/updates-available
```

The output:

```
346 packages can be updated.
229 updates are security updates.
```

No changes even after running `apt update`, as you see.

Why does it report 346 updates upon login and in `updates-available`, while `apt update` reports only 336 packages?

Comment: Your system is ~poorly maintained, if it was fully upgraded it should be reporting 18.04.5 so your server is missing more than a year of upgraded packages.  (it would have upgraded to 18.04.3 before the dated reflected on http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/08/08/ubuntu-18-04-3-lts-released/ which refers to ISO release)  When you updated the software lists (was wasn't likely done in some time), it's corrected the count with your new software lists (which may have been changed/edited since last `sudo apt update`).  I'd check whomever maintains your system & have them *pull up their socks*.

Comment: @guiverc  It's a development server running a bunch of different server software and we are a bit afraid to do some bigger updates, like from 18.04.2 to 18.04.5; we have been already burnt with some seemingly minor updates breaking some things. So, at this point I will have to install security updates only. But still, why the number of packages went backwards by 10? I would expect that apt update should find more packages after being unused for some time, not less?